# Listing the functions defined in a package

Tags: packages, documentation

Assume that I know a package's (Context?) name that is loaded. Now I want to list the functions defined in this package. How can I do it?

I remember that I found a way once, but I cannot re-find it. I tried some combinations with `?` but for vain.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Possibly this way:

```
<< PrimalityProving`

?PrimalityProving`*
```

or alternatively (see the copy&paste issue in the comments)

```
?"PrimalityProving`*"
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

See also the help under `ref/Information`, subsection "Generalizations & Extensions". In some cases you *have* to provide a string argument:

```
Information["*Values"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: In version 7 I need ``?"PrimalityProving`*"`` (string).  Is this no longer the case in v8?
`

Comment: With 8.04 it works without quotes . I´ll add the quoted version.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard this is just a copy/paste issue that arises from pasting ``?PrimalityProving`*`` into a cell after something else. It doesn't paste correctly in 8 either but will work without the quotes in either version if pasted into a cell on its own or typed in directly.

Comment: @OleksandrR. strange indeed - the asterisk is colored magenta when pasted.

Comment: The above lists all the public functions. In addition, doing ``Context`*`*`` will list the functions in the `` `Private` `` context and other subcontexts nested one level (most packages do not go beyond that). I've found some neat helper functions that way...

Comment: @R.M I´d say this information would merit another answer, perhaps with a nice [example](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8713/131)?

Answer (score 16):

Another possibility:

```
<< PrimalityProving`

Names["PrimalityProving`*"]
```

> ```
>    {CertificateDiscriminant, CertificateK, CertificateM,
>     CertificateNextPrime, CertificatePoint, CertificatePrime, fact,
>     HilbertPolynomial, ModularInvariantj, PointEC, PointECQ,
>     PrimeQCertificate, PrimeQCertificateCheck, ProvablePrimeQ}
> ```

Comment: Of course you'd want to use this form, with explicit mention of `Names`, in case you were trying to get the list of package names from within other code.

Answer (score 11):

I made a little interactive thing ('reportPackages') that often proves helpful. It lives in my own utilities package:

```
?? reportPackages
```

> reportPackages::usage = 
>         "reportPackages produces a window with a SetterBar and a button. 
>         The SetterBar lists all currently linked Packages (from $Packages).
>         The button produces a clickable list of exported Symbols of a
>       selected Package. 
>         Clicking a symbolname gives its usage note if present ";

```
    reportPackages := 
  DynamicModule[{pakket, functies}, 
   Column[{SetterBar[Dynamic[pakket], $Packages, 
       Appearance -> "Row"], 
      Column[{Dynamic[functies = pakket <> "*"], 
        Button["info", 
         Information[Evaluate[functies], LongForm -> False]] }] }] // 
    Framed];
```