# Build a refined grid based on intersecting line

Tags: computational-geometry, algorithm, grid-layouts, mesh

I honestly have no idea where to begin with this problem. In summary, I have a 2D coarse grid with an intersecting line. For an easy example, let's assume it's a 4x4 grid.

[image: Coarse Grid with intersect.]

I wish to pass through each grid block multiple times and subsequently divide each grid block in half that either has the line passing through it (or possibly through one of its vertices).

[image: 1st pass]
[image: 3rd pass]
[image: 4th pass]

...etc.

After a set number of passes, I want to assign a property to each grid block that is intersected. (example, set color to blue).

[image: Assign properties]

The only requirement is the algorithm provide the final set of refined grid blocks have at least one shared side until the termination points. The final output would be a list of vertices and their cartesian coordinates.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** The grid blocks (which will eventually total in the millions) will have CPU intensive calculations performed on them.  So the ideal solution will only refine the grid block size close to the line while leaving the areas away from the line in their "coarse" state.

Comment: Is this a homework question by any chance?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, Nope. An attempt to solve a problem the industry software gurus have yet to provide a solution to. If you think it's a homework problem due to my awesome Visio graphics, I thank you.

Comment: Useful algorithms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99353/how-to-test-if-a-line-segment-intersects-an-axis-aligned-rectange-in-2d

Comment: I'd love to to this one; it's not very difficult either, but I'm on vacation and my iPad doesn't run mma yet. The approach would be a recursive algorithm that finds all squares in your grid through which the segment goes using the above link. Each square is then divided in four sub squares on which the same function is recursively run. An additional depth parameter is decreased with every call and is used as a stopping criterion.

Comment: out of curiosity what is the industry application?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, Think a glorified pressure profile with the line being a pressure source or drawdown.

Comment: Possibly useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691491/implementing-a-quadtree-in-mathematica

Comment: This maybe of use: http://bit.ly/OYLK1d

Comment: I call Bresenham.

Comment: @kalewallace I just came across this [quadtree decomposition](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/QuadTreeImageDecomposition/) of an image in a different answer. You might want to also look into that to see if the code/approach there helps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is my implementation using `Graphics` primitives and rules. Here's the final result; the implementation details and edge cases follow.

[image]

#### 1. General approach

First, we start with a single square and build up a test grid:

```
square = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}];
grid = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None], 
   Table[Transpose@First@square + {i, j} // Transpose // Polygon, {i, 4}, {j, 4}]}];
```

[image]

For use in a later step, I'm translating the square explicitly here instead of using `Translate` or `GeometricTransform`, which remains in the `FullForm` (`Normal` doesn't get rid of it either, although it does for simple cases)

Next, I define a function `intersectQ` that tells you whether a line segment intersects a polygon. This uses an internal function `` Graphics`Mesh`IntersectQ ``, which is only available in v8 onwards.

```
Clear@intersectQ
intersectQ[line_, poly_] := Or @@ With[
    {l = Developer`PartitionMap[Line, First@poly /. {x_, y__} :> {x, y, x}, 2, 1]}, 
    Graphics`Mesh`IntersectQ[{line, #}] & /@ l
]
```

The logic is simple — check to see if the line intersects any of the sides of the polygon (**Note:** make sure to read section 3 below).

Next, a function/rule that divides a square if a line passes through it (using the above test):

```
Clear[divide]
divide[line_] := p : Polygon[v_] :> 
    With[
        {c = Mean@v, s = (Most@# + Rest@#)/2 &[v /. {x_, y__} :> {x, y, x}] /.
             {x__, y_} :> {y, x, y}}, 
        Polygon@{v[[#]], s[[# + 1]], c, s[[#]]} & /@ Range@4
    ] /; intersectQ[line, p]
```

Finally, we apply this to the grid and an arbitrary line to get the refined grid:

```
refGrid = With[{line = Line[{{3/2, 5/2}, {9/2, 9/2}}]},
    Show[Nest[# /. divide[line] &, grid, 3], Graphics[{Red, line}]]]
```

You can nest this how many ever times you want.

#### 2. Obtaining the coordinates of the top-right corners of the grids

To get the top-right vertex from each grid block (left image), you can do:

```
Cases[refGrid, Polygon[v_] :> 
    With[{c = Mean@v}, Select[v, ArcTan @@ (# - c) == π/4 &]], Infinity]~Flatten~1
```

[image]

or get them just for the intersecting grids by using the above with `intersectQ` (right image)

[image]
[image]

#### 3. Edge cases

ruebenko [pointed out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8700/build-a-refined-grid-based-on-intersecting-line/8713#comment25040_8713) some edge cases wherein lines that overlap with an edge of the grid are not considered as intersecting the grid. This is what it looks like at present:

[image]

Notice that the third and fourth large grids in the first row are not divided properly.

One simple way [suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8700/build-a-refined-grid-based-on-intersecting-line/8713#comment25048_8713) by ruebenko was to find the area of the triangle formed by the end-points of the line and each vertex of the polygon — if the area of any triangle is 0, then it is overlaps with an edge. This is good, but fails when the end-points of the line and the end-points of the edge are collinear, but the line and the edge don't overlap.

A mathematical solution to this can be obtained by recognizing that a line segment $L$ and a polygon $P$ are both convex sets. So a line can be conclusively said to be touching a polygon or intersecting it if

$$\exists\ \{x,y\}: \{x,y\}\in L \bigwedge \{x,y\}\in P$$

We can tell *Mathematica* exactly that to get our condition:

```
Clear[divideQ]
divideQ[line_, poly_] := divideQ[line, poly] = 
    Resolve[
        Exists[{x, y}, 
            With[{P = Array[p, 4], Q = Array[q, 2]}, 
                Exists[P, {x, y} == (P.First@poly) && Total@P == 1 && 
                    (And @@ Thread[P >= 0])
                ] && 
                Exists[Q, {x, y} == (Q.First@line) && Total@Q == 1 && 
                    (And @@ Thread[Q >= 0])
                ]
            ]
        ], Reals
    ]
```

Now simply use the above condition instead of `intersectQ` in section 1 above and you're all set. I've used memoization so that the result for the same polygon-line pair is cached. Using this, the above edge case is taken care of:

[image]

While this is a bit slower than the earlier one, it is cleaner and correct for all cases. If one knows well in advance that there are no such edge cases, you could go with `intersectQ`. All the figures in this answer barring the incorrect one for the edge case were done using `divideQ`.

Comment: How did you get to ``Graphics`Mesh`IntersectQ``? Makes me wonder (again) what kind of badly desired [CAGD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-Aided_Design) goodies are already available...

Comment: @R.M, It seems your method is quicker than wxffles, works with multiple line segments (although if they cross, it seems to blow up), but doesn't quite provide as "crisp" of graphics. One question: what is the easiest way to grab the top right vertices coordinates from each grid block?

Comment: @YvesKlett I don't remember... I found that (and other related functions) when looking for something else. They're all undocumented though, so you'll have to spend some time figuring out what the arguments are. Another one I've used a few times is ``Graphics`Mesh`PolygonArea@poly`` to compute the area of a polygon.

Comment: @R.M, it shows in notifications that you responded, but I'm not seeing it here... I can only see the first few words. Also, is there a way to Parallelize this for increased speed?

Comment: @kalewallace I'm not sure about parallelizing off the top of my head (will give it a try later when I have some time).

Comment: @kalewallace Getting the top-right corners of all blocks is actually fairly simple, regardless of vertex ordering (assuming square, as in this case). Try this: `Cases[i, 
  Polygon[v_] :> 
   With[{c = Mean@v}, Select[v, ArcTan @@ (# - c) == π/4 &]], 
  Infinity]~Flatten~1`, where `i` is the final refined grid output above

Comment: @R.M, +1; I don't want to be a spoil sport, here are some special cases: Line[{{3/2, 5/2}, {9/2, 5/2}}],Line[{{4, 0}, {4, 1}} + 1], Line[{{2, 4}, {4, 4}} + 1] and  Line[{{1, 3}, {5, 3}}] which all seem to be related to the same issue.

Comment: @R.M, Here is an example: It seems that `Graphics`Mesh`IntersectQ[{Line[{{1, 3}, {5, 3}}], #}] & /@ {Line[{{2, 
     2}, {3, 2}}], Line[{{3, 2}, {3, 3}}], Line[{{3, 3}, {2, 3}}], 
  Line[{{2, 3}, {2, 2}}]}` is not quite right: `Graphics[{{Red, Line[{{1, 3}, {5, 3}}]}, {Line[{{2, 2}, {3, 2}}], 
   Line[{{3, 2}, {3, 3}}], Line[{{3, 3}, {2, 3}}], 
   Line[{{2, 3}, {2, 2}}]}}]`

Comment: @ruebenko Thanks for catching this edge case — I missed it. I noticed similar behaviour with ``Graphics`Mesh`InPolygonQ``, wherein points on the edges of the polygon return `False` (which made sense, because it is not _in_ the polygon), but didn't expect that here (and didn't test it fully). I guess the edge cases can be special-cased... Hmmm. Will have to think of a way to do it without turning it into a nearly full-blown `intersectQ` implementation

Comment: @R.M, Here is an idea: you could take the two line (end)points and one polygon point. Compute the det of this triangle. Take next point from polygon, compute det for all points in polygon. If dets have all same sign and are not 0 then there is no intersection. You might want to consider caching the triangle det computation.

Comment: @ruebenko Thanks, that should work. I'll implement this later in the day.

Comment: @ruebenko I've fixed it — see my section 3 above. I went with a different approach, because using polygon area == 0 while simple, failed in cases where the line is not touching the polygon, but the endpoints were collinear to those of an edge.

Comment: @kalewallace ruebenko spotted a few edge cases where it didn't work. Please see my update, specifically section 3 in the edit that fixes it

Comment: @R.M, well there is always one more special case.... good alternative. Concerning performance, it might then be better to test segment/segment intersection (which could be compiled) and split the polygon into segments. But yeh, there is always something to improve....

Comment: @R.M, Thanks for all the help with this. You guys are scary good.

Comment: @kalewallace You're welcome. I had fun doing it :)

Answer (score 16):

Here's my go at it.

This tells you if two line segments intersect (unless they lie on the same line, in which case it fails horribly):

```
ClearAll[segmentsIntersect];
segmentsIntersect[{a_, b_}, {p_, q_}] :=
  Module[{s, t, soln},
    soln = NSolve[a + t (b - a) == p + s (q - p), {s, t}];
    If[Length@soln == 0, False, (0 <= s <= 1 && 0 <= t <= 1) /. soln[[1]]]];
```

This does the box-segment intersection using the above:

```
ClearAll[segmentIntersectsRectangle];
segmentIntersectsRectangle[
  segment : {a : {ax_, ay_}, b : {bx_, by_}},
  r : Rectangle[{minx_, miny_}, {maxx_, maxy_}]
] :=
If[minx <= ax <= maxx && miny <= ay <= maxy || 
  minx <= bx <= maxx && miny <= by <= maxy, True,
  segmentsIntersect[segment, {{minx, miny}, {minx, maxy}}] ||
  segmentsIntersect[segment, {{minx, miny}, {maxx, miny}}] ||
  segmentsIntersect[segment, {{maxx, maxy}, {minx, maxy}}] ||
  segmentsIntersect[segment, {{maxx, maxy}, {minx, maxy}}]];
```

These functions can be replaced with an efficient and correct algorithm or your choice.  Also, here will be where you decide whether corners and edges are in or out.

This recursively refines a given box:

```
ClearAll[refine];
refine[segment_, r : Rectangle[{minx_, miny_}, {maxx_, maxy_}], n_] :=
  If[n > 0 && segmentIntersectsRectangle[segment, r], 
    With[{midx = (minx + maxx)/2, midy = (miny + maxy)/2}, {
      refine[segment, Rectangle[{minx, miny}, {midx, midy}], n - 1],
      refine[segment, Rectangle[{midx, miny}, {maxx, midy}], n - 1],
      refine[segment, Rectangle[{minx, midy}, {midx, maxy}], n - 1],
      refine[segment, Rectangle[{midx, midy}, {maxx, maxy}], n - 1]
    }], r];
```

This creates some graphics:

```
Clear[refinedGrid];
refinedGrid[segment : {{ax_, ay_}, {bx_, by_}}, n_] :=
  Module[{
    minx = Floor[Min[ax, bx]],
    miny = Floor[Min[ay, by]],
    maxx = Ceiling[Max[ax, bx]],
    maxy = Ceiling[Max[ay, by]]},
    Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black],
      Table[refine[segment, Rectangle[{x, y}, {x + 1, y + 1}], n],
        {x, minx, maxx - 1}, {y, miny, maxy - 1}],
      Red, Line[segment]}]]
```

As so:

```
refinedGrid[{{0.5, 0.5}, {4.5, 2.5}}, 4]
```

[image: 1]

Exercise for the reader:

[image: 2]

Comment: Nice approach. However, I'd start with a predefined coarse grid and then refine from there, not have a varying grid based on length/direction of line. The method overall seems slower than R.M.'s, but as you show (and I'll have to study to figure out) that it works for non-linear shapes.

Comment: The more I study your algorithm, the more I like it. I've made it use a set coarse grid and parallelized it to make it quicker as well. How much performance penalty is due to the `NSolve`?

Comment: @kalewallace, I am sure you could improve on the performance of NSolve. You could code (e.g. compile) the **symbolic** solution to `Reduce[a + t (b - a) == p + s (q - p), {s, t}]` and just insert coords.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you:

```
ClearAll[linesquares]
linesquares[coords_, n_] := Module[{image},
  image = Rasterize[Graphics@Line[coords], RasterSize -> 2^n, ImageSize -> 2^n];
  Position[ImageData@image /. {1., 1., 1.} -> "", {_, _, _}]
  ]

linesquares[{{1, 1}, {4, 3}}, 3]

(*

{{6, 7}, {6, 8}, {7, 6}, {7, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 4}, {8, 5}, {8, 6}, {8, 7}, {9, 3}, {9,4}, {9, 5}, {10, 1}, {10, 2}, {10, 3}, {10, 4}, {11,1}, {11, 2}}

*)
```

And to render the output:

```
Graphics[Rectangle /@ linesquares[{{1, 1}, {4, 3}}, 3]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphic]

Comment: Nice, but--and as I will now update my question--all grid blocks will eventually have very CPU intensive calculations performed on them. So where your method, it seems, involves a immediately refined grid, I want to start with a coarse grid and then only refine the areas close to the line (to save CPU cycles).