# How to check if a 3D point is in a planar polygon?

Tags: computational-geometry

Following up on [ndroock1's question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9405), I naively tried to apply the solutions to a 3D point and polygon and they didn't work. For example, functions involving `ArcTan` that are used in [kguler's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9408/9)
don't work with three arguments, [Mac's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9415/9) doesn't consider the 3rd dimension at all, the undocumented function `` Graphics`Mesh`PointWindingNumber `` doesn't work in 3D, and [complex numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9418/9) only map to 2D planes. And so on.

So, is there any way to **check if a 3D point is in a 3D planar polygon?**

Comment: Why not just apply a linear transformation sending the polygon's plane to the xy plane and proceed from there?

Comment: @whuber I was thinking about that, but I'm not that familiar with `FindGeometricTransform`.

Comment: @EliLansey, you could compute the normal *n* to the plane by taking the `Cross` product of two vectors in the plane, and then use `RotationMatrix[{n,{0,0,1}}]` to get a rotation matrix which will rotate everything into the xy plane.

Comment: @Simon, for polygons with inexact coordinates, it'd be safer to use Newell's algorithm to compute the normal...

Comment: @SimonWoods That's a great idea. Want to write it up as an answer?

Comment: I project everything to the plane of the polygon, including the polygon vertices, presuming they are not precisely coplanar, then treat as  2d. You can also then naturally have a critera for rejecting a point based on distance from the plane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **Version 10**, we can use `RegionMember` to select points that are within a region; whether we're dealing with points in a 3D polygon or a 2D polygon embedded in 3D. Let's take a look at the latter case which is what the OP asks:

We create a triangle embedded in 3D, discretize it and collect points we know for sure are in the triangle:

```
tri = Triangle[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}];
dt = DiscretizeRegion[tri, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.000001];
intri = MeshCoordinates[dt]; (* points in triangle *)
```

Now we generate random points and mix them with the points created above:

```
pts = Join[RandomReal[1, {5000, 3}], intri];
```

We create a `RegionMemberFunction` and apply it to all points to determine which points are inside/outside the polygon:

```
rm = RegionMember[dt]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice how this tells us we're dealing with a 2D region embedded in 3D. We apply it to all points:

```
inout = rm[pts];
colors = inout /. {True -> Red, False -> Blue};
```

Visualize:

```
Graphics3D[{Transpose[{colors, Point /@ pts}], EdgeForm[Black], Opacity[0], tri}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 11):

**Just work in local coordinates for the polygon's plane.**  This requires finding a change of basis matrix and then applying it (which is just matrix multiplication).

One way to obtain a basis is to use any three points on the polygon, assuming they are not collinear.  Thus:

```
basis[{x_, y_, z_, ___}] := Orthogonalize[{y - x, z - x}] // Transpose;
```

(`Orthogonalize` is not really necessary but it assures the transformation preserves distances and angles for applications that might need that.)

Right-multiplication by `basis[...]` converts 3D coordinates to 2D coordinates (ignoring any component of the 3D coordinate orthogonal to the polygon's plane). Then apply whatever 2D algorithm you prefer.

#### Example

Let's generate a random 3D polygon and another random point:

```
{vertices, p} = Through[{Most, Last}[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {4, 3}]]];
```

To illustrate the use of `basis`, here are the 3D and local 2D renderings of this configuration:

```
Graphics3D[{Polygon[vertices], PointSize[0.02], Darker[Red], Point[p]}]
With[{a = basis[vertices]},
  Graphics[{Lighter[Gray], Polygon[ vertices . a], Darker[Red], PointSize[0.02],  Point[p . a]}]]
```

[image: Two plots]

---

One check that the point actually is in the plane of the polygon is achieved this way:

```
inPlane[p_, basis_, origin_] := Abs[Det[Append[Transpose[basis], p - origin]] ] < 10.^(-12)
```

The `origin` must be a point known to be in the plane (such as one of the polygon's vertices).  *E.g.*,

```
inPlane[#, basis[vertices], First[vertices]] &  /@ Append[vertices, p]
```

> {True, True, True, False}

verifies that the triangle does lie in its plane and, as it happens, this particular point does not.

Comment: Can you give more detail about checking if the point is in the plane?

Comment: @Eli: equation 18 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html) might give you a clue on how to do the checking. (I used it in the `coplanarQ[]` function I mentioned in another comment.)

Comment: One way to safen the implementation of `basis[]` would be to take the `Mean[]` of the polygon's points and use that as the `x`... on another note, for your `inPlane[]`, might it be better to do the test as `Chop[Det[(* stuff *)]] == 0`?

Comment: @J.M. Right; `Chop` works well. I considered using the centroid, but it potentially has similar numerical problems for many polygons. If you're worried about this, perhaps the most efficient approach is to choose, say, five or six vertices at random and for the basis calculation use three that form a sufficiently large angle between them.  A less efficient but very stable and trustworthy method is to take the first two principal components in an SVD of the vertices(considered as a $3$ by $n$ matrix)  relative to their centroid: that is, a centered PCA.

Comment: Hah, nice! I forgot that PCA can do the job here, even though it is not the most efficient way to go about things... but safe nevertheless.

Comment: @J.M. Then you might prefer this: `basis[vertices_] := 
 First[SingularValueDecomposition[vertices - Mean /@ vertices]][[All, 
  1 ;; 2]]`

Comment: I'd do `First[SingularValueDecomposition[vertices - Mean /@ vertices, 2]]` myself... but wait, shouldn't that be `# - Mean[vertices] & /@ vertices` (i.e., `Standardize[vertices, Mean, 1 &]`)?

Comment: @J.M. and whuber: I like the centered PCA approach, how would one get the normal vector of the plane of the 3D polygon if PrincipalComponents is used?

Comment: @Rainer Assuming the points are very close to coplanar, the smallest eigenvalue will be close to zero and much smaller than the other two. The eigenvectors associated with the other eigenvalues--that is, the first two principal components--thereby span a plane passing close to most of the points.  This gives two solutions: (1) The cross product of the first two principal components will be a normal vector for that plane. (2) The third principal component will be orthogonal to the other two, whence it too is a normal vector for the plane.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the hints I now succeeded in defining a nice, stable function to get the normal vector of a 3D polygon even if this is not exactly planar: `GetPolygonNormal[vertices_] := 
 Last[Last[
    SingularValueDecomposition[# - Mean[vertices] & /@ 
      vertices]]\[Transpose]]`

Answer (score 4):

I use the algorithm described [here](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/insidepoly/) for convex 3D polygons. Basically, if a point is inside a polygon, the sum of the angles between the point and each pair of vertices should be $2\pi$, otherwise it's outside the polygon. The angle between two vectors is given by $$\theta=\arccos\left[{\vec a\cdot\vec b\over \|\vec a\|\|\vec b\|}\right].$$
So,

```
inPolyQ[poly_,pt_]:=2.π==Total[ArcCos[
  Dot@@@#/Times@@@Map[Norm,#,{2}]&@Transpose@{#,RotateRight[#]}
 ]]&@(#-pt&/@poly)
```

This only works for a convex polygon, however. Additionally, this doesn't check if the polygon is, in fact, planar.

**Edit** As per J.M.'s comment, this can be simplified using the `VectorAngle` function:

```
inPolyQ[poly_,pt_]:=2.π==Total[
  VectorAngle@@@Transpose@{#,RotateRight[#]}
 ]&@(#-pt&/@poly)
```

Comment: You know there's a `VectorAngle[]` function, don't you?

Comment: @J.M. Doh! Well, that'll make this simpler-looking...

Comment: Here is a not-very-efficient way to check if a set of given points are all coplanar: `coplanarQ[pts_?MatrixQ] := If[Length[pts] < 4, True, And @@ ((Chop[Det[PadRight[#, {4, 4}, 1]]] == 0) & /@ Subsets[pts, {4}])]`.

Comment: An alternative implementation for `inPolyQ[]`: `inPolyQ[pt_?VectorQ, poly_?MatrixQ] := Chop[Total[VectorAngle @@@ Partition[(# - pt) & /@ poly, 2, 1, {1, 1 - 2 Boole[TrueQ[First[poly] == Last[poly]]]}]] - 2 π] == 0`.

Comment: @J.M. What are the benefits of your approach?

Comment: I prepared for the possibility that the first and last entries in the point list being the same, among other things. I use `Chop[stuff] == 0` as the test, in the event that `(angle sum) - 2 π` is a tiny nonzero number that should be zero, but isn't.

Comment: If your polygon is a convex polygon, then you could use a modification of my approach in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8713/5) (see `divideQ` in "3: Edge cases"). So just join the point to the centroid, say, and check if there exists any convex combination of the sides that will give you that line. If it does, then the point is on the polygon. Such an approach certainly won't be blitzing fast, but if you don't have many points and polygons (and not too many arbitrary sides), then it's an alternative. In any case, you seem to have two solutions already