# Code to give center of circle given three points in 2D?

Tags: functions, geometry

Does anyone know how to make a function like this:

```
C(p1,p2,p3)=center of circle that goes through p1, p2, and p3?
```

This is in 2D

Comment: Off topic, of course. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103405/what-is-the-algorithm-for-finding-the-center-of-a-circle-from-three-points ... or http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle.html ir you're eager to know more

Comment: See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16209/how-to-determine-the-center-and-radius-of-a-circle-given-three-points-in-3d -- even though it's 3D, some of the answers can be adapted.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumcenter.html

Comment: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2003/Jan/msg00019.html

Comment: The easiest most brain-dead solution is probably to use `FindInstance` and specify that the distance from each point to a point `{x,y}` should be the same.

Comment: I think this post should be reopened just to put in the answer `Circumsphere[{p1, p2, p3}]` - it will help people who land on this page via google search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have this old converted code stashed away here, but it isn't very good. I don't know how to handle the case where the points are collinear... Perhaps someone can improve on this and make it more *Mathematica*-y.

```
circleThrough3Points[{p1_, p2_, p3_}] := 
 Module[{ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, centerx, 
   centery, r},
  {ax, ay} = p1;
  {bx, by} = p2;
  {cx, cy} = p3;
  a = bx - ax;
  b = by - ay;
  c = cx - ax;
  d = cy - ay;
  e = a (ax + bx) + b (ay + by);
  f = c (ax + cx) + d (ay + cy);
  g = 2 (a (cy - by) - b (cx - bx));
  If[g == 0, False,
   {centerx = (d e - b f)/g,
    centery = (a f - c e)/g, 
    r = Sqrt[(ax - centerx)^2 + (ay - centery)^2]
    }];
  {centerx, centery, r}]
```

In action:

```
Manipulate[
 {centerx, centery, radius } = circleThrough3Points[{p1, p2, p3}];
 Graphics[
  {White,
   Rectangle[{-100, -100}, {100, 100}],
   Black,
   Circle[{centerx, centery}, radius]
   }
  ],
 {{p1, {0, 50}}, Locator},
 {{p2, {50, 50}}, Locator},
 {{p3, {50, 0}}, Locator},
 ContentSize -> {250, 250}]
```

[image: points and circles]

Comment: Another way is in [ClickPane](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ClickPane.html?q=ClickPane&lang=en) documentation in `Applications` section.

Comment: To deal with colinear points: `circleThrough3Points[...] := 
 Module[{...},  
  If[Abs[Normalize[(p2 - p1)].Normalize[(p2 - p3)]] == 1,
   Inset["Colinear", Scaled[{.5, .5}]],
   (*your stuff*)Circle[{centerx, centery}, r]]]` and just put this in graphics.