# Obtaining arc from a DXF file

Tags: import, geometry

I have [DXF File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s25uwko9o656t7q/Arco.dxf?dl=1) that contains an arc.

I did the procedure to import a DXF file and generate a `Graphics3D` as below:

```
Import["C:\\Users\\Leandro\\Desktop\\Arco.dxf","Graphics3D"]
InputForm[%]
```

The image below is the output I get, but is not very useful for me:

[image: output]

Question: Is it possible to create a function whose output would be something like:

```
Graphics[{Circle[{75,129.90381057},{150,150},{4.1887902,5.23598776}]}]
```

Would someone have an idea of ​​how to at least use these lines to determine the center and radius?

Comment: When you post a file that is on dropbox, the link you get when you choose to share it often ends in a "..dl=0", and when people open the link it takes them to a webpage where they then have to click somewhere to download the file.  If you change the "0" to a "1", then the link becomes a direct link to the file.

Comment: I changed, but for me it appears an error.

Comment: Odd, when I click it now, it downloads directly. Not that my phone knows what to do with it once downloaded....

Comment: OK then. See you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy, if you have 10.0 or higher:

```
data = 
Cases[
   Import["D:\\Users\\Sjoerd\\Downloads\\Arco.dxf", "Graphics3D"], 
   Line[a___] :> a, 
   Infinity
][[1, All, {1, 2}]]
```

> {{-7.10543*10^-14, 
>     3.42197*10^-11}, {6.90143, -3.74717}, {13.9895, -7.12801},  {21.2448, -10.1333}, {28.6475, -12.7547}, {36.1771, -14.9851}, 
>   {43.8132, -16.8183}, {51.5348, -18.2494}, {59.3207, -19.2745}, 
>   {67.1496, -19.8906}, {75., -20.0962}, {82.8504, -19.8906}, {90.6793, 
>   -19.2745}, {98.4652, -18.2494}, {106.187, -16.8183}, {113.823, 
>   -14.9851}, {121.353, -12.7547}, {128.755, -10.1333}, {136.01, 
>   -7.12801}, {143.099, -3.74717}, {150., 3.41913*10^-11}}

```
{center, radius} = List @@ Circumsphere[data[[{1, Length[data]/2 // Round, -1}]]]
(* {{75., 129.904}, 150.} *)
```

For versions earlier than v10, have a look at my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10957/an-efficient-circular-arc-primitive-for-graphics3d).

Comment: Note that this works for circular arcs only, but I believe this was asked here

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't download your data for some reason, so I'll use the one in Sjoerd's answer, which I assigned to `myArc`.

You have a number of points with inexact coordinates, so I would not rely too much on being able to compute the circumcircle. A safe method is to use the ones in [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16209); the one in [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23115) there is quite compact:

```
{a, b1, b2, c} = Flatten[Last[SingularValueDecomposition[Flatten[{Norm[#]^2, #, 1}] & /@
                                                         myArc, -1]]];
{cen, rad} = {-{b1, b2}/(2 a), Sqrt[(b1^2 + b2^2)/(4 a^2) - c/a]};

Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[myArc], Circle[cen , rad]}]
```

[image: given points and associated circle]

To get just the arc itself, do this:

```
{θ1, θ2} = ArcTan @@@ (TranslationTransform[-cen] /@ myArc[[{1, -1}]]);
Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[myArc], Circle[cen , rad, {θ1, θ2}]
```

or this

```
(* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10994 *)
arc[center_?VectorQ, {start_?VectorQ, end_?VectorQ}] := Module[{ang, co, r},
    ang = VectorAngle[start - center, end - center];
    co = Cos[ang/2]; r = EuclideanDistance[center, start];
    BSplineCurve[{start, center + r/co Normalize[(start + end)/2 - center], end}, 
                 SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                 SplineWeights -> {1, co, 1}]]

Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[myArc], arc[cen, myArc[[{1, -1}]]]}]
```

Both should yield the following picture:
[image: the arc itself]