# Intersection coordinates of two spheres

Tags: equation-solving, geometry, regions, intersection

I am trying to obtain a list of coordinates at which two spheres intersect.

Take for example the spheres: `sp1=Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]`
and 
 `sp2=Sphere[{1, 1, 1}, 1.5]`
When I Plot them it is clear they intersect, but i cannot retrieve the coordinates.

So far I Tried finding them by looking for the nearest or RegionNearest between `RandomPoint[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], 1000]` and `RandomPoint[Sphere[{1, 1, 1}, 1.5],1000]`. Nor did it work by looking for Intersection of the two list (since no coordinates actually matched)
I also tried to look for the minimal euclidean distance between all points and the positions of those minimal distances, but in that case my computer crashes. 
Can somebody help? Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems simple enough to compute analytically (pen and paper) that it might not be worth bothering with the numerical approach ...

Comment: I suggest this interesting read: [Sphere-Sphere Intersection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html)

Comment: it takes just a little tweaking to generalize that mathworld solution to the case where the spheres are not along a coordinate axis..

Comment: In my example it is simple enough for pen and paper, but i want to do it for 180 different and more complicated spheres, which makes it useful to be able to let mathematica take care of it. And I had seen the sphere sphere intersection explanation and notebook, but dont see how i can apply it to my spheres.

Comment: What do you mean by "a list of coordinates" for the intersection? Just sampling the region?

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5968) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16209) might be useful.

Answer (score 6):

```
sp1 = Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1];
sp2 = Sphere[{1, 1, 1}, 1.5];
ri1 = RegionIntersection[sp1, sp2];
l = MeshCoordinates[DiscretizeRegion[ri1]];
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], sp1, sp2, Thick, Red, 
   Line@l[[Last[FindShortestTour[l]]]]}]]
```

[image: intersecting spheres]

Note that you can find the center and radius of the circle with:

```
o = Mean[l];
r = Mean[Table[Norm[l[[i]] - Mean[l]], {i, Length[l]}]];
```

The normal of the circle is naturally in the direction of either of the centers of the spheres.

Comment: +1 - Now the question is, can you reorder the points so that they can be used in a `Line`, via `Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], sp1, sp2, Red, Thick, Line@l}]`?

Comment: @JasonB added the center and radius of the circle. Unfortunately `Circle[]` doesn't work in `3D`.

Comment: @Feyre - it seems in this example you can use `FindShortestTour`:  This works:  `Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], sp1, sp2, Red, Thick, 
  Line@l[[Last@FindShortestTour@l]]}]`

Comment: @JasonB Yes, updated the answer

Answer (score 4):

This answer uses the `circle3D` function written by Taiki, found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79793/9490).  But it specifically does not use any of the `Region` functionality to find the intersection.  Instead, I just grabbed some formulas from [this MathWorld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html)

```
circle3D[centre_: {0, 0, 0}, radius_: 1, normal_: {0, 0, 1}, angle_: {0, 2 Pi}] :=
  Composition[
    Line,
    Map[RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, normal}, centre], #] &,
    Map[Append[#, Last@centre] &, #] &,
    Append[DeleteDuplicates[Most@#], Last@#] &,
    Level[#, {-2}] &,
    MeshPrimitives[#, 1] &,
    DiscretizeRegion,
    If
  ][
    First@Differences@angle >= 2 Pi,
    Circle[Most@centre, radius],
    Circle[Most@centre, radius, angle]
  ]

sphereIntersection[{x1_, r1_}, {x2_, r2_}] := 
  Module[{dvec, d, d1, r},
   dvec = x2 - x1;
   d = Norm@dvec;
   d1 = (d^2 + r1^2 - r2^2)/(2 d);
   circle3D[x1 + d1 Normalize[x2 - x1], Sqrt[r1^2 - d1^2], 
    Normalize[x2 - x1]]
   ];
sphereIntersection[s1_Sphere, s2_Sphere] := 
 sphereIntersection[List @@ s1, List @@ s2]
```

Using the OP's spheres, you can visualize it via

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.3], sp1, sp2, Opacity[1], Blue, Thick, 
  sphereIntersection[sp2, sp1]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can grab the points via

```
Cases[Graphics3D[sphereIntersection[sp2, sp1]], 
 Line[{a__}] :> a, Infinity]
```

or just get random points via

```
RandomPoint[sphereIntersection[sp2, sp1]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the results from [this MathWorld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html):

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom["spherical"];
            c1 = RandomReal[1, 3]; c2 = RandomReal[1, 3];
            r2 = RandomReal[3/2]; r1 = RandomReal[3/2];
            d = EuclideanDistance[c1, c2];
            u = (d^2 + r1^2 - r2^2)/(2 d^2); cc = {1 - u, u}.{c1, c2}; 
            rc = Sqrt[r1^2 - d^2 u^2];
            Graphics3D[{Opacity[1/2], Sphere[c1, r1], Sphere[c2, r2],
                        {Red, Tube[BSplineCurve[
                                   AffineTransform[{RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1},
                                                    Normalize[c2 - c1]}], cc}][
                                   rc PadRight[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1},
                                                {-1, 0}, {-1, -1}, {0, -1}, {1, -1},
                                                {1, 0}}, {Automatic, 3}]], 
                                   SplineClosed -> True, SplineDegree -> 2, 
                                   SplineKnots -> {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/4, 1/2,
                                                   1/2, 3/4, 3/4, 1, 1, 1},
                                   SplineWeights -> {1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1,
                                                     1/Sqrt[2], 1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1}]]}},
                       Boxed -> False]]
```

[image: two intersecting spheres]

---

Here's a variation using `CirclePoints[]` to evenly sample the circle:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom["spherical"];
            c1 = RandomReal[1, 3]; c2 = RandomReal[1, 3];
            r2 = RandomReal[3/2]; r1 = RandomReal[3/2];
            d = EuclideanDistance[c1, c2];
            u = (d^2 + r1^2 - r2^2)/(2 d^2); cc = {1 - u, u}.{c1, c2};
            rc = Sqrt[r1^2 - d^2 u^2];
            n = 30;
            Graphics3D[{Opacity[1/2], Sphere[c1, r1], Sphere[c2, r2],
                        {Red, Sphere[AffineTransform[{RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1},
                                                      Normalize[c2 - c1]}], cc}][
                                     PadRight[ArrayPad[CirclePoints[rc, n],
                                                       {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, "Periodic"],
                                              {Automatic, 3}]], 1/100]}}, Boxed -> False]]
```

[image: crown of spheres]

Comment: [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JGiZ5.png) is the corresponding picture for the OP's case.

Comment: +1 Showing off your Spline skills I see

Comment: @Jason, it was just a means to an end. ;) Let me edit this to include a variation...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simply sample the intersection, you can do this:

```
RandomPoint[
   ImplicitRegion[
    RegionMember[
     RegionIntersection[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], 
      Sphere[{1, 1, 1}, 1.5]], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}], 100] // 
  Point // Graphics3D
```

[image]

This *should* work, but maybe it doesn't because of the single-dimensional nature of the sampling region:

```
RandomPoint[
     RegionIntersection[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], 
      Sphere[{1, 1, 1}, 3/2]], 100] // Point // Graphics3D
```

Comment: Also, you can construct actual solutions for equations involved around `RegionMember`, but that needs more specific information of what you're really after.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just generate the parametric equations for the intersection of the spheres?  You know that the intersection points form a circle in a plane perpendicular to the vector between the centers of the spheres.

```
sphereIntersection[{x1_, r1_}, {x2_, r2_}, th_] :=

  Module[{dvec, d, d1, r, rr, ss, nx, ny, nz},
   dvec = x2 - x1;
   d = Norm@dvec;
   dvec = {nx, ny, nz} = Normalize@dvec;
   d1 = (d^2 + r1^2 - r2^2)/(2 d);
   If[r1^2 < d1^2, Return[$Failed]];
   r = Sqrt[r1^2 - d1^2];
   rr = {1 - nx^2/(1 + nz), -nx ny/(1 + nz), -nx};
   ss = {-nx ny/(1 + nz), 1 - ny^2/(1 + nz), -ny};
   x1 + d1 dvec + r (Cos[th] rr + Sin[th] ss)];
sphereIntersection[s1_Sphere, s2_Sphere, th_] := 
 sphereIntersection[List @@ s1, List @@ s2, th]
```

You get your equation via

```
sphereIntersection[sp1, sp2, theta] // FullSimplify
(* {(
 7 (3 + Sqrt[3]) + Sqrt[143] (3 + 2 Sqrt[3]) Cos[theta] - 
  Sqrt[429] Sin[theta])/(24 (3 + Sqrt[3])), (
 7 (3 + Sqrt[3]) - Sqrt[429] Cos[theta] + 
  Sqrt[143] (3 + 2 Sqrt[3]) Sin[theta])/(24 (3 + Sqrt[3])), 
 1/24 (7 - Sqrt[143] Cos[theta] - Sqrt[143] Sin[theta])} *)
```

And generate points via

```
sphereIntersection[sp1, sp2, #] & /@ Range[0, 2 π, π/2] // N
(* {{0.972304, 0.109291, -0.206594}, {0.109291, 
  0.972304, -0.206594}, {-0.38897, 0.474043, 
  0.789928}, {0.474043, -0.38897, 0.789928}, {0.972304, 
  0.109291, -0.206594}} *)
```

And plot it via

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], sp1, sp2}],
 ParametricPlot3D[
  sphereIntersection[sp1, sp2, theta], {theta, 0, 2 π}, 
  Evaluated -> True]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You might want to see [this paper](http://orbit.dtu.dk/files/57573287/onb_frisvad_jgt2012.pdf).

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, it's better without using a random number to generate the basis vectors

Comment: I know; I was actually trying to look for this paper when I saw your solution. Apart from that little typo I've now fixed, it's pretty nice!