# SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"] returned evaluating DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection between two spheres

Tags: regions, memory

Trying the code in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121093/27539), in particular the `RegionIntersection` part, I get, on v10.4.1 under windows, a

```
Throw::sysexc: Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. Can be caught with Catch[\[Ellipsis], _SystemException]
Out[] = SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]
```

In particular, this error is given evaluating the following simple code (WARNING: this may hang your system for a while):

```
DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[
    Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1],
    Sphere[{1, 0, 0}, .5]
  ]
```

Can someone replicate this (thus making it most probably a bug of the last versions of MMA), or is it just me?

Comment: Don't use floating points `DiscretizeRegion@
 RegionIntersection[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], Sphere[{1, 0, 0}, 1/2]]`

Comment: It works for me (MMA 11, Ubuntu 15.10) _the first time_ I run it. The second time, I get `Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. Can be caught with Catch[\[Ellipsis], _SystemException].`. Not using floats works.

Comment: @Feyre not using floats works. Still, I'm guessing the system should not be so unstable to crash if floating point numbers are used for the radius, right? Can you replicate the error in that case?

Comment: @glS I get the error, but also use `10.4`, so I guess it's fixed in `11`.

Comment: I get the exception on both V11.0.0 and V10.4 under Linux Mint 17.3 (each time I run the code)

Comment: I send this to the developers for investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a hunch I found Specifying `MaxCellMeasure` helps.

```
DiscretizeRegion[
 RegionIntersection[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], Sphere[{1, 0, 0}, .5]]
 , MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1]
```

[image]

As it is a 2d plot, you need very small `MaxCellMeasure` for a neat circle:

```
MaxCellMeasure -> 0.00001
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good workaround, thanks. I think we can say that this is a bug anyway, so I'll also report it to the wolfram support.

Comment: @glS Aye, tis that.