# How to show well the convexhull in 3d?, for a given set of points

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I´m trying with

```
alfa = 0.75
p = {{1, 0, 0}, {alfa, 0, 1 - alfa}, {alfa, 1 - alfa, 0}, {0, alfa, 
   1 - alfa}, {0, 1 - alfa, alfa}}

chull = ConvexHullMesh[p];
Show[HighlightMesh[chull, Labeled[1, "Index"]], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[p, 0.05]}], Axes -> True, Boxed -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

but only create the convexhull of the first 4 points.

I don´t know what´s the problem to create the convexhull with the last.

Comment: Yes @Öskå , I know :-) but it is not important for this case :-)

Comment: @Öskå When coding sometimes I use alfa instead alpha because in spanish both words sounds in the same way. I ought to use the latin letters with the esc ... esc sequence :-) but... I´m not used to use it but it´s a good thing, Yes :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you generate random points using `p = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {5, 3}]` then your code works fine -- suggesting that the problem has to do with the fact that all your points lie in a plane. A simple solution is to perturb one of the points slightly outside the plane:

```
alfa = 0.75;
p = {{1,0,0}, {alfa,0,1-alfa}, {alfa,1-alfa,0}, {0,alfa,1-alfa}, {0,1-alfa,alfa+0.0000001}};    
chull = ConvexHullMesh[p];
Show[HighlightMesh[chull, Labeled[1, "Index"]], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[p, 0.05]}], Axes -> True, Boxed -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Do you think that´s an error that should be commented to wolfram?

Comment: @MikaIke The docs say "Convex hull meshes are full dimensional", i.e, in 3D the hull should be a 3D region.  I think it ought to give a warning message at the least. For instance, `DelaunayMesh[p]` gives an error.

Answer (score 4):

There's a related question,
[A problem on generating convex hull](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30392/a-problem-on-generating-convex-hull/30402#30402), and I can adapt my answer there to this case.  The basic approach is to map the points in the plane to a 2D coordinate system, find the hull in 2D, and embed the hull in the plane in 3D.

I inserted an extra point in the interior, because that sometimes causes trouble when it is dropped in the `BoundaryMesh`. The [`ConvexHull`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ConvexHull.html) is basically the [`BoundaryMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BoundaryMesh.html) of the [`DelaunayMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DelaunayMesh.html) of the points.

```
alfa = 0.75;
p = {{1, 0, 0}, {alfa, 0, 1 - alfa}, {alfa, 1 - alfa, 0}, {0, alfa, 
    1 - alfa}, {0, 1 - alfa, alfa}};
p = Insert[p, Mean[p], 3];

coordMat =                        (*coordinate projection matrix*)
  DeleteCases[Orthogonalize @ Differences @ p, v_ /; v == {0, 0, 0}];
coords = p.Transpose[coordMat];   (*2D coordinates*)

hull = DelaunayMesh[coords];
```

At this point we have a triangulation of the convex hull in `hull`.  The simplest thing is to map this back to 3D.  A little more work is needed to convert it to a `BoundaryMeshRegion` like `ConvexHullMesh`, which appears as the second solution.

```
chull = MeshRegion[p, MeshCells[hull, 2]];
Show[
 HighlightMesh[chull, Labeled[1, "Index"]],
 Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[p, 0.05]}],
 Boxed -> True, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The `BoundaryMeshRegion` version:

```
bhull = BoundaryMesh@hull;
nf = Nearest[MeshCoordinates[hull] -> Automatic];
tobpts =                        (* needed because BoundaryMesh drops interior points *)
  MapIndexed[First@#2 -> First@nf[#] &, MeshCoordinates[bhull]];
chull = MeshRegion[p, MeshCells[bhull, 2] /. tobpts];
Show[
 HighlightMesh[chull, Labeled[1, "Index"]],
 Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[p, 0.05]}],
 Boxed -> True, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that there is an important difference between them, if you want to highlight the line elements.