# ConvexHull peculiar behaviour - bug? (Definitely not a feature)

Tags: bugs, regions, computational-geometry, crash

I ran in the last few days into a problem which I was afraid I couldn't solve:
I use a set of 12 points in 3D to define a region and test whether and if how many other points lie inside this region. I used `ConvexHull[]` on the 12 points to define the region and then simply `RegionMember[]` for the test.

However, for certain positions of these 12 points the kernel just shut down, without running into RAM problems. Is this a known issue? I use here Mathematica 10.2. Just to be able to test this here is an example code which kills everytime my kernel:

```
(*8x 12points after a lengthy computation*)
test={{{1.`, 1.`, 5333.333333333333`}, {1.`, 800.`,5333.333333333333`},{600.5`, 400.5`, 0.`}, {600.5`, 400.5`,5333.333333333333`},{1200.`,1.`,5333.333333333333`}, {1200.`, 800.`, 5333.333333333333`},{58042.552333112566`, -38206.400563704345`, 19374.67514613655`},{58334.25743941619`, -38734.91563377405`, 18851.24324830685`}, {58525.314741500944`, -38713.1081147315`, 19545.52131899129`}, {58716.372043585696`, -38691.30059568895`,20239.79938967573`}, {59008.07714988933`, -39219.81566575865`, 19716.36749184603`}, {62483.79825981317`, -35344.65017352293`,18350.38794651614`}},
{{1.`, 1.`,5333.333333333333`}, {1.`, 800.`,5333.333333333333`}, {600.5`,400.5`, 0.`}, {600.5`, 400.5`, 5333.333333333333`}, {1200.`, 1.`,5333.333333333333`}, {1200.`, 800.`, 5333.333333333333`}, {25869.10601275226`,-20033.469429356493`, 10006.45364321929`},{26269.363331591725`, -20404.815082668127`,9423.103418669753`}, {26554.859683382878`, -20246.27216215559`,10065.253304186597`}, {26840.35603517403`, -20087.729241643054`,10707.403189703442`}, {27240.613354013494`, -20459.074894954687`,10124.052965153904`}, {28180.172063134924`, -15530.123404949865`,8178.259660165485`}},
{{1.`, 1.`,-5333.333333333333`}, {1.`, 800.`, -5333.333333333333`}, {600.5`,400.5`, -5333.333333333333`}, {600.5`, 400.5`, 0.`}, {1200.`, 1.`, -5333.333333333333`}, {1200.`, 800.`, -5333.333333333333`}, {62483.79825981317`,-35344.65017352293`, -18350.38794651614`}, {62743.673933721235`,-30067.648628019182`, -19374.67514613655`}, {63347.238653729575`,-30056.261042864524`, -18851.24324830685`}, {63423.809574513405`,-30232.656492513917`, -19545.52131899129`}, {63500.380495297235`,-30409.05194216331`, -20239.79938967573`}, {64103.945215305575`,-30397.664357008656`, -19716.36749184603`}},
{{1.`, 1.`, -5333.333333333333`}, {1.`, 800.`, -5333.333333333333`}, {600.5`, 400.5`, -5333.333333333333`}, {600.5`, 400.5`, 0.`}, {1200.`, 1.`, -5333.333333333333`}, {1200.`,800.`, -5333.333333333333`}, {28180.172063134924`, -15530.123404949865`, -8178.259660165485`}, {30926.38377214352`, -11278.127055695275`, -10006.45364321929`}, {31448.041575476618`, -11439.299794518214`, -9423.10341866975`}, {31453.354516395335`, -11765.820539938006`, -10065.253304186597`}, {31458.66745731405`, -12092.341285357797`, -10707.403189703442`}, {31980.32526064715`, -12253.514024180738`, -10124.052965153904`}}, 
{{1.`, 1.`,5333.333333333333`}, {1.`, 800.`, 5333.333333333333`}, {600.5`, 400.5`, 0.`}, {600.5`, 400.5`, 5333.333333333333`}, {1200.`, 1.`, 5333.333333333333`}, {1200.`, 800.`, 5333.333333333333`}, {62483.79825981317`, -35344.65017352293`, 18350.38794651614`}, {65959.51936973701`, -31469.48468128722`, 16984.40840118625`}, {66251.22447604063`, -31997.999751356918`, 16460.976503356556`}, {66442.2817781254`, -31976.192232314366`, 17155.25457404099`}, {66633.33908021015`, -31954.384713271815`, 17849.532644725427`}, {66925.04418651378`, -32482.89978334152`, 17326.100746895732`}},
{{1.`, 1.`, 5333.333333333333`}, {1.`, 800.`, 5333.333333333333`}, {600.5`, 400.5`, 0.`}, {600.5`, 400.5`,5333.333333333333`}, {1200.`, 1.`, 5333.333333333333`}, {1200.`, 800.`, 5333.333333333333`}, {28180.172063134924`, -15530.123404949865`, 8178.259660165485`}, {29119.730772256356`, -10601.171914945044`, 6232.466355177065`}, {29519.988091095816`, -10972.517568256677`, 5649.116130627529`}, {29805.48444288697`, -10813.97464774414`, 6291.266016144374`}, {30090.980794678122`, -10655.431727231604`, 6933.4159016612175`}, {30491.238113517582`, -11026.777380543239`, 6350.06567711168`}},
{{1.`, 1.`, -5333.333333333333`}, {1.`, 800.`, -5333.333333333333`}, {600.5`,400.5`, -5333.333333333333`}, {600.5`, 400.5`, 0.`}, {1200.`, 1.`, -5333.333333333333`}, {1200.`, 800.`, -5333.333333333333`}, {60863.65130432076`,-40291.635990037204`, -16984.40840118625`}, {61467.21602432911`, -40280.24840488255`, -16460.976503356553`}, {61543.78694511293`, -40456.64385453195`, -17155.254574040995`}, {61620.35786589677`, -40633.039304181344`, -17849.53264472543`}, {62223.9225859051`, -40621.65171902669`, -17326.100746895736`}, {62483.79825981317`, -35344.65017352293`, -18350.38794651614`}},
{{1.`, 1.`, -5333.333333333333`}, {1.`, 800.`, -5333.333333333333`}, {600.5`, 400.5`, -5333.333333333333`}, {600.5`, 400.5`, 0.`}, {1200.`, 1.`, -5333.333333333333`}, {1200.`, 800.`, -5333.333333333333`}, {24380.018865622696`, -18806.73278571899`, -6232.466355177068`}, {24901.6766689558`, -18967.90552454193`, -5649.116130627528`}, {24906.989609874516`, -19294.426269961717`, -6291.266016144374`}, {24912.302550793233`, -19620.947015381513`, -6933.41590166122`}, {25433.96035412633`, -19782.119754204454`, -6350.065677111683`}, {28180.172063134924`, -15530.123404949865`, -8178.259660165485`}}};
```

Now if I do

```
ConvexHullMesh/@test
```

it kills my kernel.
If I do it indiviually I found out that it is the third array which seems to kill the kernel, the rest is calced just fine:

```
ConvexHullMesh[test[[3]]]
```

After isolating the problem I finally found the solution: 
Michael E2 mentioned in this post: [see answer by Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71453/how-to-show-well-the-convexhull-in-3d-for-a-given-set-of-points/71468#71468) that the `ConvexHull` is basically the `BoundaryMesh` of the `DelaunayMesh` of the points.
So if I do

```
BoundaryMesh[DelaunayMesh[test[[3]]]]
```

or this

```
BoundaryMesh[DelaunayMesh[#]] & /@ test
```

it works and I can test for `RegionMember`, e.g. by

```
 RegionMember[#, {1.`, 800.`, -5333.333333333333`}] & /@ regs
```

I am positive that this behaviour of `ConvexHullMesh` is not intended.

Comment: I can confirm that the third element of `test` will crash my kernel. If you run ``Point@test[[3]] // Graphics3D`` it seems likely that the issue is that it's so long and narrow.  Maybe the algorithm gets trapped trying to find solutions.

Comment: I'll let you off the hook for this, since I have confirmed it, but next time, please don't jump the gun and use the [tag:bugs] tag until other people have confirmed it.

Comment: This happens also in version 11.3. Curiously, it works when I scale `test[[3]]` by `1/10` before calling `ConvexHullMesh`...

Comment: Filed as [CASE:4042640].

Comment: @J.M. so, how do I go about about posting a question when I think it is not a bug? Simply not use the bug-tag?

Comment: Yes, just ask the question like you would normally do, and let someone else add the [tag:bugs] tag on your behalf after confirmation. This is all discussed [here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/192) and other meta threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I supposed that it had to be an uncatched error in the TetGen library for the kernel quits without warning. However, using `TetGenLink` directly seems to work and may serve as a workaround until `ConvexHullMesh` is fixed.

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"];
myConvexHullMesh[args__] := Module[{pts, triangles},
  {pts, triangles} = TetGenConvexHull[args];
  BoundaryMeshRegion[pts, Triangle[triangles]]
  ]
```

This is also a bit faster than `BoundaryMesh@*DelaunayMesh` since it skips the tetrahedralization.